# How to find the client ip address from a HttpHeaders object in java?

Tags: java, http-headers, ip, client

How to find the client ip address from a HttpHeaders object in java?

Please find my server side code below:

```
@Path("/login")
public class Login
{
    DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String checkLogin(@QueryParam("username")String username,@QueryParam("password")String password,@QueryParam("clientid")String clientno,@QueryParam("callback")String callback,@Context HttpHeaders headers)
    {

        JSONObject loginresult = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            String query = QuerySelector.getQuery("user.checklogin");
            loginresult = dBConnection.queryForJSONObject(query, username,password,clientno);
           //here i need to get the client ip address from my headers object.        

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return callback + "(" + loginresult.toString() + ")" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the client ip would be in the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to get it via `@Context HttpServletRequest request` simply like:

```
String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

New method signature:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String checkLogin(@QueryParam("username")String username,@QueryParam("password")String password,@QueryParam("clientid")String clientno,@QueryParam("callback")String callback,@Context HttpServletRequest request)
```

Comment: I know, that is not the problem to get rquest in this case. You can get via context not only httpheades object

Comment: So i have to pass  HttpServletRequest as well from the client side?Is there any other way without changing my client side code?

Comment: You just have to inject HttpServletRequest insteadof HttpHeaders in your checkLogin method as a parametre. No need to change a client, you always have a request in your web service implementation call

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
request.getHeader("Remote_Addr");
```

If it returns null then try :

```
request.getRemoteAddr();
```